# Android Apply Palette

Tags: android, android-palette

I am trying to use the palette function of androids material design but I am having some trouble in applying it.

I have successfully generated the palette and now I am trying to pass the palette into a function that applies the it.

The problem that I am having is that when I pass in the palette to the `applyPalette` function none of the methods like `palette.getDarkMutedColor().getRgb() , palette.getVibrantColor().getRgb()` are being populated with the values from the palette.

The tutorial that I was following didnt mention anything else other then passing in the palette to the function, and in doing so the methods would be populated

This is the generator Function and the applying function, can any one see why this isnt working?

**Code**

```
private void colorize(Bitmap photo) {
    Palette palette = new Palette.Builder(photo).generate();
    applyPalette(palette);
}

private void applyPalette(Palette palette) {
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(palette.getDarkMutedColor().getRgb()));

    TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleView.setTextColor(palette.getVibrantColor().getRgb());

    TextView descriptionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    descriptionView.setTextColor(palette.getLightVibrantColor().getRgb());

    colorRipple(R.id.info, palette.getDarkMutedColor().getRgb(),
            palette.getDarkVibrantColor().getRgb());
    colorRipple(R.id.star, palette.getMutedColor().getRgb(),
            palette.getVibrantColor().getRgb());

    View infoView = findViewById(R.id.information_container);
    infoView.setBackgroundColor(palette.getLightMutedColor().getRgb());

    AnimatedPathView star = (AnimatedPathView) findViewById(R.id.star_container);
    star.setFillColor(palette.getVibrantColor().getRgb());
    star.setStrokeColor(palette.getLightVibrantColor().getRgb());
}
```

Comment: try with removing getRgb() function.

Comment: No that didnt help still have the same error

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say the color functions "do not work".

Comment: I get an error underlining each saying `DarkMutedColor (int) in Palette cannot be applied to 0`

Comment: Which version of Palette are you using (e.g. 21.0.0)?

Comment: I have no idea, the only dependencies I have `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}` should I be using another one for the palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use picassopalette third party library and import it into your project then use following code:

```
try {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(OtherUserProfileScreenActivity.this);
        Picasso.with(this).load(image + ".jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading).error(R.drawable.ic_error).into(imageView, PicassoPalette.with(Image + ".jpg", imageView).use(PicassoPalette.Profile.MUTED_DARK).intoCallBack(new BitmapPalette.CallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onPaletteLoaded(Palette palette) {

                int mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary);
                mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor);
            }
        }));
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.gc();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I amnt looking to use a third party library

Answer (score 0):

You have tried in synchronous way. So I think below code will solve your problem(In asynchronous way).

```
private void colorize(Bitmap photo) {   
Palette.from(photo).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                applyPalette(palette);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried replacing my code with your but still same error

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html), all of the calls you are using from `Palette` already return an RGB value but require a default color be passed. Perhaps you meant to use the ones that return a color swatch instead? For example, instead of doing this `palette.getVibrantColor().getRgb()` you would instead do this `palette.getVibrantSwatch().getRgb()` instead. Replace all your get*Color calls with the appropriate get*Swatch() call.

Also, make sure that you have `import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette` in your imports and that you include `compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.1.0'` in your dependencies. Version 22.1.0 being the minimum as you are using `Palette.Builder`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I already had these included and imported

Answer (score 0):

First thing I don't know why you didn't get error when you write

```
palette.getVibrantColor().getRgb()
```

I will assume you didn't get error ,so you must be using the old library. As in the updated one it accepts one parameter as default color value.
To extract RGB better thing is to get `Palette.Swatch` object and get RGB values.
I did create a small working simple app to demo how to use the improved library , You can check that [here](https://github.com/ashwanijanghu/Android-Palette-Demo). Hope this helps.